# Java: Possible to add 1 non-Comparable object to a TreeSet?

Tags: java, set, ocpjp

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    TreeSet<Dog> d = new TreeSet<Dog>();
    d.add(new Dog());
    System.out.println(d.size());
}

class Dog{
}
```

As you can see, the `Dog` class is not a `Comparable` object and I sure did not specify a `Comparator` to be used for sorting. How does this snippet of code run without exceptions? It printed out `1`.

I tried adding another `Dog` to the TreeSet and it threw a `ClassCastException` as expected.

EDIT: I'm using Java 6

Comment: I do get a `ClassCastException` in Java 7. The first element added should be compared to itself. I believe this change was made to catch that edge case.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to state that I was working with Java 6.

Comment: add one more element and you will get what you are looking for :)

Comment: @Mak Yeah I know haha. It's just that I was expecting it to throw the exception once I added a non-Comparable object for the first time :P

Comment: @MiguelPortugal :) Java people are working hard to fix such issues as you can see now its fixed in Java 7 and you do get Exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a change added in [Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html) to fix this. It was an error.

> Due to an error in `java.util.TreeMap`, **it was previously possible to
>   insert invalid null elements and elements not implementing `Comparable`
>   into empty `TreeMap`s and `TreeSet`s**. Only a single invalid element could
>   be inserted into the empty `TreeMap`s or `TreeSet`s; additional elements
>   would cause the expected `NullPointerException` or `ClassCastException`.
>   Most other operations upon the collection would also fail. As of JDK
>   7, inserting an invalid null element or an element not implementing
>   `Comparable` into an empty `TreeMap` or `TreeSet` throws a
>   `NullPointerException`.

(`TreeSet` is implemented with a `TreeMap` as its underlying data structure.)

Comment: hmmm, interesting, looks like they didn't update the javadoc for TreeSet though.

Comment: @CamiloBermúdez I'm trying to interpret the javadoc you quoted in your answer to make it fit with the change, but it doesn't sound good. They should have updated that too. The implementation  just compares the first element to itself.

Comment: I also see this in the JDK 7 source code. Now there is a special case class cast to Comparable, forcing an exception even when there is nothing to compare with.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add%28E%29) that's the expected behavior, it will throw a ClassCastException only if the new element cannot be compared with the current elements in the set:

> ClassCastException - if the specified object cannot be compared with the elements currently in this set

**EDIT**

However, this is valid for JSE6, apparently the javadoc for TreeSet in JSE7 is out of date, since as @SotiriosDelimanolis points out, this problem was solved for JSE7.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice trick. You are not getting exception because you didn't added more than one object as only then you need to compare the object which will end up throwing exception.